# How to load keyframe from imported (@use) Sass file?

Tags: css, sass

**(Dart Sass)** I am attempting to load the following keyframes located in `_global.sass` into `local.sass`. I have tried several implementations of calling bgGradient, but none have worked so far.

`_global.sass`

```
@keyframes bgGradient
    0%
        background-position: 0% 50%
    50%
        background-position: 100% 50%
    100%
        background-position: 0% 50%
```

`local.sass`

```
@use '_global' as global
div.wrapper
    animation: global.bgGradient 15s ease
```

*Receiving the following error:*

```
Syntax Error: SassError: expected "(".
    animation: global.bgGradient 15s ease infinite
                                ^
```

Answer (score 2):

`@keyframes` is not a scss/sass feature but rather plain css. Therefore you cannot "use" it like you would variables, mixins or functions.

Input:

```
// _globals.sass

$width: 20px

@keyframes bgGradient
    0%
        background-position: 0% 50%
    50%
        background-position: 100% 50%
    100%
        background-position: 0% 50%

.foo
    width: $width
```

```
// local.sass

@use 'global'

div.wrapper
    width: global.$width
    animation: bgGradient 15s ease
```

Output:

```css
@keyframes bgGradient {
    0% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
    50% { background-position: 100% 50%; }
    100% { background-position: 0% 50%; }
}

.foo {
    width: 20px;
}

div.wrapper {
    width: 20px;
    animation: bgGradient 15s ease;
}
```

Note how `.foo` and `@keyframes bgGradient` are both included in the output.
This means that as long as you `@use` the partial that has some keyframes *somewhere* you'll be able to use those keyframes throughout all the sass files that make up your `local.css` file, Just like `@import` would work.